# NULL safe equal to operator in C++

Tags: c++

Consider below code:

**BST.h**

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include <iostream>

typedef char Key;
typedef int Value;
#define NULL 0

class BST{

private:
    class Node{
      Key key;
      Value value;
      Node* left;
      Node* right;
      int N;
    public:
      Node(Key key='A',Value value=NULL,Node* left=NULL,Node* right=NULL,int N=0):
      key(key),value(value),left(left),right(right),N(N)
      {
       std::cout << "(Node created) Key: " << key << " Value : " << value << std::endl; 
       N++;
      }
      int getN()
      {
       return N;
      }
      bool operator==(Node& node)
      {

          if (this->key == node.key && this->value == node.value && this->left == node.left && 
              this->right == node.right && this->N == node.N)
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
    };

Node& Root;

public:

    int size();
    int size(Node& node);

};


#endif
```

And
**BST.cpp**

```
#include "BST.h"
#include <iostream>


int BST::size()
{
 return size(Root);
}

int BST::size(Node& node)
{
 if(node == NULL)//here
     return 0;
 else
     return node.getN();
}
```

I am getting compilation error at `//here` in the code.

```
bst.cpp(12): error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\users\gaurav1.k\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\bst\bst\bst.h(30): could be 'bool BST::Node::operator ==(BST::Node &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(BST::Node, int)'
```

One way to resolve the error is change the equal to operator as:
`bool operator==(Node* node)`

How do I resolve this error when I am passing node as reference .i.e.
`bool operator==(Node& node)`

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to test for with `if(node == NULL)`? If it is for a "default" then you could use `if(node == Node())` instead.

Comment: careful with you constructore. value can not be NULL, only left and right can have a value of NULL, since they are the only pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`node` is a reference so it *can't* be `NULL` or `0` *ever*.